# What to do about "The Components object is deprecated. It will soon be removed." in dev tools Console

Tags: firefox, deprecated, firefox-developer-tools

For almost every page I open in Firefox, I see this error in the Console of the developer tool bar:

> (!) The Components object is deprecated. It will soon be removed.

The source is the html page. It happens with pages I create, but also on many common websites.

I found this documentation on [Components object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Language_Bindings/Components_object) on MDN web docs, but that does not clarify a lot. Note that even that page shows this message(!)

It looks like a warning, but according to the Console filter, it is an error.

My main questions are:

- Is this something for me, as a developer of the page reporting this, to solve?
- If so, how do I go about that?

I am not aware of any problems as a result of this. For now, that is.

I have seen this for over a year, maybe longer. I mostly ignore this, but every now and then it starts nagging me again. I don't want my code to break suddenly and would like to get rid of this message obscuring other messages.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

This is not for the developer of the page to solve.

While biking back home, a possible cause popped up in my mind: could one of the add-ons I use cause this and yes, that appears to be the case.

I restarted with disabled add-ons and the message was gone.

Then I enabled them one at a time and **the culprit is
[Selenium IDE](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-ide)**.

A [bug report on this issue](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-ide/issues/598) was closed with *Won't fix*, with the message:

> This error will resolve itself when we move to a native app later this year.

In a [MozillaZine topic](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=12355853#p12355853) of 2012, it is explained how it could have been solved.

> The first one is just a warning that the addon is using "Components"
> directly, which won't necessarily always be possible when using the
> Add-on SDK. (The preferred way to do it is to access the aliases for
> Components.classes and Components.interfaces and such that the SDK
> provides by requiring the "chrome" module.) It shouldn't be a problem
> right now, but might become one in the future.

Comment: Messages like this one should not be exposed to web content at all. I wanted to file a bug report about it, but it seems it already got fixed in Firefox 71 Beta. At least there I don't see that error message being logged to the console.

Comment: I'm seeing this today in Firefox 81.0.2, so it looks like the people at Selenium haven't yet achieved what they intended.

Comment: still seeing this in firefox 98.0.2

Comment: still present in firefox 99.0

Comment: Still there in 104.0.2. Luckily I found this answer because I had no clue what it was about.

Comment: still found in 109.0 (64-bit)

Comment: And still seeing it with Selenium 3.17.4 released in 2022. So much for "later this year".

Comment: now on 113.0.2 ... still there.

Comment: Thanks, I disabled Selenium and message disappeared (firefox 116)

Comment: Still in Firefox 118 - Disabling Selenium does the trick.

Answer (score 21):

it happened for me after installing Selenium plugin in my FireFox.